# how to turn off wifi indicator?

Tags: wireless

I am using 14.04LTS in HP2000. At the time of log on its automatically becomes turned on( the indicator becomes orange to grey). If the wifi switch is pressed for turning it off it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Next time you log into your session click on the network indicator and then click on `Edit Connections`.

Choose the connection you're session is connected to automatically and click `Edit`. Uncheck the `Automatically connect to this network when available`. Hit `OK` and you're done.

Comment: no it is not connected automatically with any of the wireless connections.

Comment: In this case you are not connected and the indicator is just going mad.